# jquery ui datepicker back button jumps to 1899

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I must be missing some setting or something, but when I use the back button the datepicker jumps to 1899 from the current year.

Has anyone else seen this and fixed it?

(You can see the different combos I've commented out.)

```
    $('.dialog-search,#from')
   .datepicker({
    defaultDate: 'c-1m',
    dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
    //changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'fadeIn',
    duration: 200,
    //gotoCurrent: true, 
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    currentText: 'Now',
    shortYearCutoff: '+20',
    //showWeek: true,
    //firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: 'c-200:c',
    onSelect: function(selectedDate,inst) {
     $('.dialog-search,#from').val(selectedDate);
    }
   });
```

Comment: I copied all of that exactly and can't reproduce.

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue when I had multiple text inputs with the same ID, which is easy to do with MVC frameworks when you have multiple editors on page for same model class. I resolved it by explicitly specifying Id and leaving Name as is, so that model resolving works on postback.

Comment: This was the cause for me.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when calling

```
$(...).datepicker('destroy')
```

before re-initializing the datepicker.

Comment: Yes, I too experienced this when 'destroy' method is called before initializing datepicker. Date selection worked fine after removing the 'destroy' method before initializing.

Comment: Same for me. Call destroy before datepicker has initialized causes this trouble. Try to verify that datepicker exists before destroy ( like an el.hasClass("hasDatepicker")

Answer (score 1):

It happens when if you have a default instance, because in jQuery plugin its configured that default date is 1899.

We have to just find out why this when this default date code fires

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo with your code in jsfiddle and I can't reproduce your problem. Can you check it at http://jsfiddle.net/w78xX/.

Comment: You are correct - it works fine there. It must be something deeper in the code that launches the dialog that contains the datepicker.  I've seen some other people complain about this, but I can't find an answer or any hints about what could be causing this issue.

Comment: Patrick-api, can you post your entire code? Maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.
I'm populating datepicker fields with ajax and showing them on PrettyPhoto as popup.

Here is my code.

```
$( "body" ).on( "focus", ".tarih", function() {
    //$('.tarih').datepicker('destroy');
    var i = 0;
    $('.tarih').each(function () {
        //$(this).attr("id",'date' + i).datepicker('destroy');
        $(this).attr("id",'date' + i).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: new Date(2000, 1 - 1, 1)
        });
        i++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii:ss P'
The trick is to keeping your date format the same as what the back-end returns.

Comment: We only want to show date, not date time, what can we do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and adding the `useCurrent: false` resolves it.

```
.datepicker({
        useCurrent: false 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy because it happened with no code change at my project and I realise it's because of something at the browser. I was using Chrome and with Firefox was fine and even with Incognito Chrome Window was also fine.

Any idea about this? Thanks!