# jquery datetime picture showing incorrect dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using jquery datetimepicker like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LessonDateTime").datetimepicker(
    );
});
</script>
```

and when in the textbox if there is no value, it defaults to todays date and if there is a value , the datetime picker goes to 1899 as shown in the image below: 
[image]

I am using a viewmodel to bind which is below:

```
public class AppointmentViewModel
{
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AppointmentInstructorName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode =true, DataFormatString ="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm tt}")]
    public DateTime? LessonDateTime { get; set; }

    public string AppointmentLessonAddress { get; set; }


}
```

view:

```
 @{ViewBag.PageTitle = "Edit an Appointment";}
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LessonDateTime").datetimepicker(
    );
});
</script>
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.Hidden("userId", Model.UserId)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel">

            <div class="panel-heading tabbable" tabindex="0"><h1>Edit Appointment Details</h1></div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppointmentInstructorName, "Instructor Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppointmentInstructorName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LessonDateTime, "Lesson Date and Time", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LessonDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppointmentLessonAddress, "Address (if different)", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppointmentLessonAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>



                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>




        </div>
    </div>


</div>



}
```

Comment: seems like your string format for datetimes isn't correct either?

Comment: So what *exactly* is your question?   Do you want it defaulting to today's date if there is no value, or do you want to stop it from going to 1899 if there is a value?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: want it to stop going to 1899 and should go to today's today or the date in the text box if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `useCurrent:false` worked for me

```
$(function () {
        $('#LessonDateTime').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false                   
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in your datetimepicker as given below. You should declared `defaultDate in`datetimepicker`.

```
 $(function () {
            $('#LessonDateTime').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                useCurrent: false,                   
            });
        });
```

See more details from https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: i did try this but it did not work. for datepicker it works but not for datetimepicker. altleast it did not work for me

Comment: the datetime picker doesn't even pop up now.

Comment: See more details from https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: yea doesn't fix. some other users have this issue as well: https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/207  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830934/jquery-ui-datepicker-back-button-jumps-to-1899  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104564/jquery-datetimepicker-input-text-showing-date-31-12-1899-when-time-selected

Comment: you can't just copy my answer and ask me to mark it as answer?

Comment: OK. I have no problem. I did my effort.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting timestamp. You can convert it to 'normal' date. But the Best way is to set date format Type in datetimepicker